# tkinter radio buttons structured identically working in one window and not the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I have a GUI set up with radio buttons, and it opens up a secondary window with identically set up radio buttons. Somehow it works in the main window and not the other.

My code is structured like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def gui():
    # all the code to set up the rest of the GUI would go here, relevant code is below

    dirVar = tk.IntVar()
    def radioRetrieve():
        print(dirVar.get())

    dirButton0 = tk.Radiobutton(dirFrame, text = "Teachers", variable = dirVar, value = -1, command = radioRetrieve)
    dirButton1 = tk.Radiobutton(dirFrame, text = "Students", variable = dirVar, value = 1, command = radioRetrieve)
    dirButton2 = tk.Radiobutton(dirFrame, text = "Both", variable = dirVar, value = 0, command = radioRetrieve)
    dirButton0.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    dirButton1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
    dirButton2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

    def advanced():
        #creating a secondary window, radio buttons here do not work

        advVar = tk.IntVar()
        def advRetrieve():
            print(advVar.get())

        advDir0 = tk.Radiobutton(advDirFrame, text = "Teachers", variable = advVar, value = -1, command = advRetrieve)
        advDir1 = tk.Radiobutton(advDirFrame, text = "Students", variable = advVar, value = 1, command = advRetrieve)
        advDir2 = tk.Radiobutton(advDirFrame, text = "Both", variable = advVar, value = 0, command = advRetrieve)
        advDir0.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
        advDir1.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
        advDir2.pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

The buttons in my main window in `def gui()` work perfectly fine. The buttons in the secondary window initiated by `def advanced()` do not; I just keep getting 0s. I've also tried initializing the second `IntVar` in the `def gui()` instead of `def advanced()`, no luck. Everything else in the secondary window works also, just not the radio buttons. I've combed through all the code, the code for the two sets of radio buttons are structured identically. Am I missing an obvious typo?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`?

Comment: advanced() is another Tk, yes.

Comment: Unless you understand the ramifications, you should be using `Toplevel` rather than `Tk` for second and subsequent windows.

Comment: amazing, that did the trick. thank you!!